# ReactJS: how to manage the state correctly in my case

Tags: reactjs

So I have a container (simplified version), it works as following:

- Step1: get the config version
- Step2: read the config file above from S3 using the version from
- Step3: once the version is loaded, set a flag isLoadLiveConfigComplete -> true, so I know I can render
- Step4: setup bunch of tabs to render depending on which one gets clicked
- Step5: render a specific tab

The problem is the state.challenges in step5 is undefined when I try to render the tab. But I have checked that in step3 it has content already.

So I’ve read that setState works in an asynchronized manner, which means I cannot use it in a sequential way.  But I have checked that data in step3 and state.challenges have been set, and I don’t render the tabs until the flag has been checked and set. Why this is still not working? Any suggestions on how to fix this in this case?

version 2 - used callbacks in 2 places:

```
class CLL_AppContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { // initial state
            tab:CLL_Constants.TABNAME_CHALLANGES,
            isLoadLoginDataComplete:false,
            isLoadLiveConfigComplete: false,
            challenges: [],
            configVersion: ""
        };
    }

componentDidMount() { // loads into browser page
    this.getLiveName(); // step1: get the configVersion
    …
}

onGetLiveName(data){
    // step2: use a callback here to make sure readFromS3() is called after configVersion is set first
    this.setState({liveConfig:data.version}, () => {this.readFromS3(this.state.configVersion)}); 
}

readFromS3(version){
    var form = new FormData();
    …
    form.append('configName', this.state.liveConfig);
    …
    // step3: read the config file from S3
    // fetchAjax() accepts a callback for when the response.success to further process the returned data  
fetchAjax(form, (data) => {
    console.log(data.configString); // yup I can see the data loaded from S3
    this.setState({challenges: data.configString.types});
    this.setState({isLoadLiveConfigComplete: true} );
})

}

render() {
    var state = this.state;

    if(!state.isLoadLoginDataComplete && !state.isLoadLiveConfigComplete) {
        return <Spinner />
    }

// step4: setup bunch of tabs to render depending on which one gets clicked
    return (
        <div>
            <div align="center">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={() => this.setState({tab: CLL_Constants.TABNAME_CHALLANGES})}>
                    {CLL_Constants.TABNAME_CHALLANGES}
                </button>
                …
            </div>
            <div>
                {this.renderTab()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

renderTab() {
    var challenges = this.state.challenges; // console.log() shows this is undefined, why???
    switch (this.state.tab)
    {
        case CLL_Constants.TABNAME_CHALLANGES:
            return (
                <CLL_ChallangesContainer
                    challenges={challenges}
                    …
                </CLL_ChallangesContainer>
            );
        …
        default:
            return (
                <Spinner />
            );
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(data.configString.types)` inside `onReadFromS3` and verify that it is not undefined?

Comment: hmmm, i thought i have done that and data.configString.types has content, but that doesn't seem to be true ;-(

Comment: @larz: I made some changes to the code, now data.configString does have content from what returned from S3. However, state.challenges is still undefined ;-(

Comment: Try batching both your `setState` calls in `fetchAjax` into a single call. There's no reason to have them separate and since `setState` is async I think it's likely the flag is being set before the data.

Comment: @lawrence-witt: the ```fetchAjax``` is a generic function that I used in a few different places, accepting the form and a callback when the Ajax call is successful and have a valid response. The callbacks are different depending on where I used it.

Comment: `this.setState({challenges: data.configString.types, isLoadLiveConfigComplete: true})`

Answer (score 0):

Truly, there is a way to "force synchronization" while using the setState. This can be achieved using the setState's call back:

```
this.setState({.... }, () => { *do after the setState is done* })
```

Some people says this could get hard to understand but

```
() => { *do after the setState is done* }
```

is just a function that you could pass as the value for a variable. Get to understand this part and the whole world of React will be at your toes!

Note: While using the mentioned callback be also careful while using "this".

Try also doing:
.....

```
const self = this
fetchAjax(form, (data) => {
    console.log(data.configString); // yup I can see the data loaded from S3
    self.setState({challenges: data.configString.types, isLoadLiveConfigComplete: true});        
})
```

....

Be careful with the use of "this"

Comment: modified the code a bit using 2 callbacks, so now data.configString in step 3 does have content. However, state.challenges is still undefined.

Comment: see what I added to my answer